# PHP7 - Can type hinting be trusted?

Tags: php, php-7, scalar

I have recently began to look into the new type hinting which was introduced in PHP 7 and found that it was a really nice and useful addition to add to some of my application therefore I have gone to do so however I have a question regarding argument and return type hinting.

So say I have a basic function which performs mathematics on two arguments and returns an integer.

```
function addTwo(int $a, int $b): int {
   return $a + $b;
}
```

The expected arguments should be integers and we should hopefully receive an integer value from the function, however is this always guaranteed or should there be further validation carried out within the function such as is_int to ensure both arguments are integers?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I have done a few tests however I am wondering if it is always guaranteed or are there some use cases which may differ and return invalid results

Comment: It will return a catchable error if what you provide to the function is not an integer, therefore you will either have an error or an int will be returned.

Comment: If you annotate a parameter to be an int, you will get an int. In PHP 7 this is strictly enforced (while in PHP 5 there were ways to circumvent the type check if you really wanted). I'd like to warn you though that your function is a bit dangerous, because the addition of two integers in PHP may return a floating point number (in case of overflow), which will lead to a return type exception. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: That's interesting, would declare(strict_types=1); prevent this issue and restrict the types to int only so that it would be impossible to return a float or would I have to perform further validation within the function?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the conditions. For example, in your example to transfer lines will not succeed, but the pass float - no problem, it will be silently converted to int.

You must write declare(strict_types=1);

strict_types=1 can only apply to a file that directly declares it on its first line, no way around that.

> Strict typing also has an effect on return type declarations. In the
>   default weak mode, returned values will be coerced to the correct type
>   if they are not already of that type. In strong mode, the returned
>   value must be of the correct type, otherwise a TypeError will be
>   thrown.

[Returning values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Comment: So just to clarify, if I had strict_types declared as true within the file, my function immediately fail upon an invalid argument call meaning that it wouldn't perform any of the actual function? The main reason I'm particularly interested in this is because I'd much rather the function fail at the start and throw a type error rather than half way through the function when it may have already performed certain tasks using invalid data types.

Comment: The function body won't be executed if there is a type error when handling the arguments.